# Extracting energy from dark energy using springs

Tags: energy, spacetime, dark-energy

So would it be possible to in theory use really giant springs to extract energy from dark energy? So let's say this spring is located outside the local group where dark energy overcomes gravity. So we could get a really big spring with a spring constant that is relatively small.  So when dark energy stretches out the spring will store energy. However, if the spring gets stretched out too much, it will bounce back with a lot of energy and we could extract this energy.

If it is possible, how much energy would be extracted? It also gets around the problem of the deSitter horizon because the springs if too extended would bounce back.

Would this be possible even in theory?

*Also in this case, energy conservation can be violated due to time symmetry violation.

Comment: What picture do you have of "dark energy" if you say "where dark energy overcomes gravity" Too many people knowing very little real physics get fascinated by dark energy and black holes. M aybe tell us what background you have in physics, or what you know about "dark energy"

Comment: Dark energy is the thing that makes the expansion of the universe get accelerated.

Comment: @trula - Dark energy overcomes the gravitational attraction of a single mass M at the radius r=³√(GM/H²) in the sense that the attraction to the mass due to M equals the acceleration away from it due to H, so at that r you have 0 net acceleration d²r/dτ²=0, see the [Schwarzschild De Sitter metric](http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=1053#p1053). In our universe which is almost, but not exactly de Sitter since H changes over time, but the order of magnitude is the same, so for a galaxy that distance is roughly a Megaparsec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be possible, you could extract the equivalent of the rest mass of a chain if it extends to the Hubble radius. If to [simplify](https://umwelt--wissenschaft-de.translate.goog/forum/naturwissenschaftliche-themen/4728-kraft-im-expandierenden-universum?start=0&_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp#95229) the [equations](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/FLRW.proper.coordinates.html#14) we assume a constant Hubble parameter $\rm H$ as it will be in the late universe the force is

$${\rm F = m \ a = m} \sqrt{|\sum_{\alpha, \beta} g_{\alpha \beta} \ {\rm a}^{\alpha} {\rm a}^{\beta}|}$$

where $\rm a^{\mu}$ is the 4-acceleration

$$\rm a^{\mu}=\frac{d^2 x^{\mu}}{d\tau^2}+\sum_{\alpha, \beta} \ \Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha \beta} u^{\alpha} u^{\beta}$$

so the force to stay at constant proper distance $\rm r$ is

$$\rm F=\frac{m \ H^2 r}{\sqrt{1-(H r/c)^2}}$$

If we integrate $\rm F$ from $0$ to $\rm r_H=c/H$ we get

$$\rm E = \int_0^{r_H} F \ dr = m c^2$$

That is assuming ideal material on the chain, a realistic one will break before it extends to the Hubble horizon and the extractable energy is less than exactly $\rm mc^2$, also see [arxiv:1911.08726](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.08726) and [DOI:10.1086/175767](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1995ApJ...446...63H/abstract)

Comment: So if the spring is shrunk again, does that mean the energy disappears?

Comment: To reverse the process you need to invest the energy you gained in the first place. Assuming a constant H that energy is conserved, as it is in the [Schwarzschild scenario](https://umwelt--wissenschaft-de.translate.goog/forum/naturwissenschaftliche-themen/4670-wie-man-ein-sl-fuettert-ohne-es-schwerer-zu-machen?start=0&_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp#90055) where you can lower a cable to the horizon to gain the energy equivalent of its rest mass.

Comment: @Yukterez As you mentioned, if we let an object (e.g. a big cannon ball) tied to a string fall into a Black Hole (described by Schwarzschild metric) we would get the  energy equivalent to the rest mass of that cannon ball. However, once the cannon ball gets "absorbed" by the Black Hole, it would be heated by the gravitational tidal forces and then emission of high-energy-radiation in form of jets and rays could occur. Then, wouldn't we get then more energy than the rest mass of the cannon ball?

Comment: @vengaq - after the ball gets absorbed the radiation produced behind the horizon can't reach the coordinate bookkeeper any longer, and the radiation produced above the horizon gets redshifted by the gravitational time dilation factor before it reaches the bookeeper relative to whom the energy is defined.

Comment: @Yukterez but even if the radiation is redshifted, it would be *some* energy. So, wouldn't we get the endrgy from the wire attached to the cannon ball + the energy that we would get as radiation (although redshifted)?

Comment: @vengaq - no, if the ball starts to dissipate into radiation before it reaches the horizon the integral of the force times distance is no longer from here to the horizon but from here to where the ball radiates away, the energy is conserved but if it radiates away in all directions most of the radiation won't reach you since parts of it fly in the opposite direction, so in total you would harvest less energy than if the ball wouldn't radiate away.